Is it OK to run electrical under floor joists in basement?
I've moved into a house with existing wiring in the basement and some wires are run under the floor joists which I believe is against code?

Is this allowed in this situation because of the HVAC ducts and other pipes?  I'm asking because I need to run another outlet and was going to drill holes through the joists but I noticed this existing wire so I thought maybe I could run the second parallel to the first.

NO.  It is not okay.
Yes, it is against code.
No, it is not allowed.
NEC 334.15(C) restricts this type of run to cables not smaller than 8/3 or 6/2.

334.15 Exposed Work
(C) In Unfinished Basements and Crawl Spaces
Where cable is run at angles with joists in unfinished basements and crawl spaces, it shall be permissible to secure cables not smaller than two 6 AWG or three 8 AWG conductors directly to the lower edges of the joists.  Smaller cables shall be run either through bored holes in joists or on running boards.

